# Como excluir TableViewCell sendo um Dicionário Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, uitableviewcell, dicionário

Estou tentando excluir um `TableViewCell` usando o estilo swipe to delete, porém não consigo deletar as cells. As cells estão sendo criadas por um dicionário que cria cada uma com a key como titulo e o value como detalhes.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    //Cria as cells pelo dicionário favDict
    for (key, value) in favDict{
        cell.textLabel?.text = key
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = value
    }

    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete {
        favDict.removeAtIndex(indexPath!.row) //Linha em que esta dando o erro, aparece que Int não é convertido para [String: String]
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

O problema será do acesso ao `indexPath`. Está a forçar a fazer *opcional unboxing* com o `!`. Na definição do método, `indexPath: NSIndexPath!` já está automaticamente a fazer o unboxing logo apenas tem que usá-lo normalmente:

**Exemplo:**

```
lista.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
```

Answer (score 0):

O problema é que você está removendo um item do `Dictionary` da forma errada.

Primeiro, você está passando um inteiro para um método que não aceita inteiro:

O método `removeAtIndex`, no caso demonstrado, espera um parâmetro do tipo `DictionaryIndex<String, String>` que pode ser obtido usando o método `indexForKey`.

Segundo, o dicionário é uma relação `Key` -> `Value`, logo, para excluir um item, você precisa informar a chave relacionada àquele valor.

Assim, para conseguir excluir um item do seu dicionário, você precisa, primeiro, achar a chave relacionada àquela posição na tabela.

```
let keyArray = Array(favDict.keys)
let key = keyArray[indexPath.row]
favDict.removeValueForKey(key)
```